Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type
I am trying to create a time Series plot using highCharter.
I am adding an xts object to a part of the code

hc_add_series(name = series_name, data = data_xts, yAxis = 0,
color="#454545")

which gives the following error

Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type

data_xts is created from a data frame where rownames are in a DATE format.
What looks like a possible error here ?

Maybe you want to convert your xts to something like a data frame or a tibble, since highCharter seems to not currently support xts objects. One option is to use the function fortify.zoo from the zoo package:
hc_add_series(name = series_name, data = fortify.zoo(data_xts), yAxis = 0, color="#454545")

or
hc_add_series(name = series_name, data = as_tibble(fortify.zoo(data_xts)), yAxis = 0, color="#454545")

